# Unexpected substitution with STL streams of C++20 concept. How did it happen?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++-concepts

There is an example compiled by LLVM 15.0.0, about the C++20 concepts. FYI. all of the code could be found here https://godbolt.org/z/zearGEe5K.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct RawStreamTraits
{
    using Ch = typename T::char_type;
};

template <typename T>
using RawStreamCharType = typename RawStreamTraits<T>::Ch;

template <typename _StreamT>
concept SameAsStdBasicInputStream = std::same_as<_StreamT, std::basic_istream<RawStreamCharType<_StreamT>>>;

template <typename _StreamT>
concept DerivedFromStdInputStream = std::derived_from<_StreamT, std::basic_istream<RawStreamCharType<_StreamT>>>;

template <typename _StreamT>
concept RawInputStream = requires {
    SameAsStdBasicInputStream<_StreamT> || DerivedFromStdInputStream<_StreamT>;
};

static_assert(RawInputStream<std::istream>); // 1
static_assert(RawInputStream<std::ostream>); // 2
static_assert(SameAsStdBasicInputStream<std::istream>);  // 3
static_assert(DerivedFromStdInputStream<std::istream>);  // 4
static_assert(SameAsStdBasicInputStream<std::ostream>);  // 5 ERR!
static_assert(DerivedFromStdInputStream<std::ostream>);  // 6 ERR!
```

I cannot understand the result. In my opinion, the 1st one and the 3rd one should be evaluated to `true`, the 4th one is uncertain,and others should be `false`.

As the 5th one and 6th one shows, `std::ostream` does not satisfy any sub-concept of `RawInputStream`, but `RawInputStream<std::ostream>` is true. That's the most confusing result.

Of course, `std::istream` is not derived from itself, or `std::basic_stream<char>`. so the 4th one should be `false`, am I right?

And, the result would not change, if you replace the `std::same_as` with `std::is_same_v`, or replace the `std::derived_from` with `std::is_base_of`, and exchange the base type and derived type.

Could anyone help me on this question? I have no idea about this result...

Comment: You have a spurious `requires` in the last concept definition. Remove it and the curly braces. See [updated version](https://godbolt.org/z/xMjcx1zsb).

Comment: "std::istream is not derived from itself" -- `std::derived_from` returns `true` if both types are the same.

Comment: yes, I have found the implementation of `std::derived_from` of LLVM, you are right.

Comment: why? It is written in the [specs](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.derived#lib:derived_from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `RawInputStream` concept you defined

```
template <typename _StreamT>
concept RawInputStream = requires {
  SameAsStdBasicInputStream<_StreamT> || DerivedFromStdInputStream<_StreamT>;
};
```

It will *only* check the validity of the expression in the `requires`-clause, without evaluating it.

You can use additional `requires` to evaluate the value and constrain it to be `true`:

```
template <typename _StreamT>
concept RawInputStream = requires {
  requires SameAsStdBasicInputStream<_StreamT> || DerivedFromStdInputStream<_StreamT>;
};
```

or just

```
template <typename _StreamT>
concept RawInputStream = 
   SameAsStdBasicInputStream<_StreamT> || DerivedFromStdInputStream<_StreamT>;
```

> Of course, `std::istream` is not derived from itself, or
> `std::basic_stream<char>`. so the 4th one should be false, am I right?

`std::derived_from` is `true` when the two template parameters are of the same class type, which is consistent with `std::is_base_of_v`, which is why `DerivedFromStdInputStream<std::istream>` is `true`.

Also, instead of using extra `RawStreamTraits` to extract the `char_type`, you can write it directly in the concept like

```
template <typename _StreamT>
concept SameAsStdBasicInputStream = 
  std::same_as<_StreamT, std::basic_istream<typename _StreamT::char_type>>;
```

Comment: The speciliazed `RawStreamTraits` is required for other streams, e.g. `std::FILE*` or socket fd in the real implementation. I ignored them in the example.
And thanks for your answer~